# What ECMAScript 6/7 standards have been implemented in Firefox and not in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I'm sorry if this has been asked before.

Some ES6/7 standards are implemented in Firefox beta versions alone and not in Chrome, and vice versa. Can anyone please list which browsers support what? Is there any single browser which implemented most of those standards.

For e.g.: I'm not able to use Object.observe in Firefox. It is available in Chrome beta v36.

Please see: Do not mark duplicate for object.observe. I'm not interested in Object.observe There are other standards as well. Please specify others compatibility too.

Comment: You can use the [table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) mentioned in the other answer to check any function.

Comment: I've no idea why thefourtheye thinks this is a duplicate of that much narrower question, but this is still overly broad. There are a lot of features in new versions of JS, and creating a browser support list would be a pretty big task … the results of which would quickly become out of date.

Comment: @quentin and  thefourtheye did you try to understand the context of the question before marking it as duplicate?

Comment: @Ashwin It is me, who marked it as a duplicate. If not duplicate, your question can be closed for other reasons. Atleast the duplicate question will give you some idea.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Still, you should have made the pointer a link in a comment, and vote to close as "too broad". I've reopened, it really was not an exact duplicate.

Comment: The answer provided by Andreas below lists it well. The issue now is how to run this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwinaggarwal/hEVes/) in chrome on my localhost.

Specifying **<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript;version=1.6"></script>** works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). It has a few mistakes in it, and glosses over the details (in particular, whether the implementation of a feature actually is complete and standard-conformant), but for most part it seems close enough.

Comment: The above table lists very well. Thanks @Andreas Rossberg.

In Firefox we can run new features by specifying version in script tag. Same does not work in Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114 m). Like this fiddle works in Firefox but not in Chrome, through above table says Chrome v35 supports generators..

Can you please help me how to run the same code in Chrome?

Comment: *[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwinaggarwal/hEVes/). Sorry I missed in my above comment.

Comment: In Chrome, you have to turn on "Experimental JavaScript features" for now (as the table says). In Firefox, new features are on by default -- its version tags actually have nothing to do with ES6/7, but with ancient FF-specific JS extensions.